# CodeIgniter some issues with subomain and subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have some problems with a codeigniter 3.0.1 installation. I have installed codeigniter into a subdirectory on a subdomain, for example subdomain.domain.com/codeigniter.

I have created an .htaccess file for remove index.php from url but when I try to access the default controller I got a 404 error.

**My htaccess file.**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**My config file**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**And my default controller in routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Auth";
```

Comment: A server 404 or a 404 page provided by codeigniter?

Comment: where did you put your .htacess file